# Magento 2 Creating table setting in admin with custom dropdowns

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm using following code to show table setting in adminhtml

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

class Test extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory
     */
    protected $_elementFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_elementFactory  = $elementFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->addColumn('min_sales_amount', ['label' => __('Min Sales Amount')]);
        $this->addColumn('max_sales_amount', ['label' => __('Max Sales Amount')]);
        $this->addColumn('test', ['label' => __('Commission')]);
        $this->addColumn('is_percent', ['label' => __('Is Percent?')]);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
        parent::_construct();
    }

}
```

Table setting appears in admin panel, but I want the field **is_percent** to contain dropdown with values "Yes" and "No", how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a method like this:

```
protected function getYesNoOptions()
{
    $this->yesNoOptions = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Options\YesNo',
        '',
        ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
    );
}
```

add 'is_percent' column:

```
        $this->addColumn('is_percent',
        [
            'label' => __('Is percentage'),
            'renderer' => $this->getYesNoOptions()
        ]);
```

Add another method to prepare data:

```
protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
{
    $options = [];

    $options['option_' . $this->getYesNoOptions()->calcOptionHash($row->getData('is_percent'))]
        = 'selected="selected"';

    $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);

}
```

Create \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Options\YesNo class

```
class YesNo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select 
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno
 */
protected $yesNo;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $yesNo,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->yesNo = $yesNo;
}


public function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getOptions()) {
        foreach ($this->yesNo->toOptionArray() as $option) {
            $this->addOption($option['value'], $option['label']);
        }
    }

    return parent::_toHtml();
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->getInputName();
}
}
```